# path not found?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to run the below against multilpe servers using Powershell 3.0 but for some reason I am getting back that the path does not exist...even though it does?

Any ideas?

CODE:

```
clear
$computer = Get-Content -path c:\temp\servers.txt

foreach ($computer1 in $computer){

Write-Host $computer1
Get-Content -Path '\\$computer1\C$\Program Files\BMC Software\BladeLogic\RSCD\rscd.log' -Tail 10

}
```

ERROR:

> SV191267 Get-Content : Cannot find path '\$computer1\C$\Program
>   Files\BMC Software\BladeLogic\RSCD\rscd.log' because it does not
>   exist. At
>   C:\Users\gaachm5\AppData\Local\Temp\e4651274-dcab-4a87-95a6-0f11437a7187.ps1:7
>   char:1
>   + Get-Content -Path '\$computer1\C$\Program Files\BMC Software\BladeLogic\RSCD\rs ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\$computer1\C$...c\RSCD\rscd.log:String) [Get-Content],
>   ItemNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
>
> SV193936 Get-Content : Cannot find path '\$computer1\C$\Program
>   Files\BMC Software\BladeLogic\RSCD\rscd.log' because it does not
>   exist. At
>   C:\Users\gaachm5\AppData\Local\Temp\e4651274-dcab-4a87-95a6-0f11437a7187.ps1:7
>   char:1
>   + Get-Content -Path '\$computer1\C$\Program Files\BMC Software\BladeLogic\RSCD\rs ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\$computer1\C$...c\RSCD\rscd.log:String) [Get-Content],
>   ItemNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
"\\$computer1\C`$\Program Files\BMC Software\BladeLogic\RSCD\rscd.log" -Tail 10
```

In single quotes `'` the variable are not expanded but treated as literal as `$computer1`, the `$` for the `$admin share` must be escaped with a backtick `

Comment: As pointed in the @HungryHippos's answer the dollar sign for the admin share does not need to be escaped 'cause is followed by a \ char, but I think it's a good practice escape the dollar sign in "string" when it's needed as literal.

Answer (score 3):

The path that can't be found only has one \ on the front of it, a UNC share must begin with two \'s. I can see from your code it looks like you are prefixing the two \'s but it doesn't look like it's being carried over.

I would use double quotes instead of single quotes as already pointed out, if you do that then you should not need to escape the $ character either.

Assuming a file called file.txt exists in the C:\temp folder on the local machine.

This fails:

```
$computer1 = "localhost"
Test-Path '\\$computer1\c$\temp\file.txt'
```

This works:

```
$computer1 = "localhost"
Test-Path "\\$computer1\c$\Temp\file.txt"
```

Comment: I've edited your answer to fix quotes in first example (the two examples were identical, apart from the capital letter T in the second one :) )

Comment: I've edited it again to actually work. It's not `$computer1` that needs double-quotes, it's the `Test-Path` string that needs to expand a variable :-)